# How to make terminal output the background of my lock screen?

Tags: command-line, lock-screen, screensaver

Currently running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with the Gnome 3 DE, and I want to change up the default Gnome lock screen. How would I change my lock screen background to display arbitrary terminal output? I'd like to run a specific command upon displaying the lock screen.

Comment: You mean when screen lock activates it takes a picture of your current `gnome-terminal` stretches it to full screen and displays it as wallpaper?

Answer (score 0):

**Set the `org.gnome.desktop.screensaver.picture-uri` key**

1. Create the gdm profile which contains the following lines:

   `/etc/dconf/profile/gdm`

   ```
   user-db:user system-db:gdm
   file-db:/usr/share/gdm/greeter-dconf-defaults
   ```

   `gdm` is the name of a dconf database.
2. Create a `gdm` database for machine-wide settings in `/etc/dconf/db/gdm.d/01-screensaver`:

   ```
   [org/gnome/desktop/screensaver]
   picture-uri='file:///opt/corp/background.jpg'
   ```
3. Replace `/opt/corp/background.jpg` 
   with the path to the image file you want to use as the lock screen background.
   Supported formats are PNG, JPG, JPEG, and TGA. The image will be scaled if necessary to fit the screen.
4. Update the system databases:

   ```
   dconf update
   ```

You must log out before the system-wide settings take effect.

Next time you lock the screen, the new lock screen shield will show in the background. In the foreground, time, date and the current day of the week will be displayed.

If the background does not update
Make sure that you have run the [dconf](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/dconf.html.en) update command to update the system databases.

In case the background does not update, try restarting GDM.